# Filename 'file' is too long or invalid Visual Studio 2010 and 2012

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I've found an interesting error when I tried to build a .Net 3.5 class library, and I've got this error in visual studio 2012.

```
Error   201 File name '..\..\..\..\B2B.Common\Documentation\
FooBarBaz.Core.Providers.ScheduledTaskProviders
.foobarbazSearchAlerting.XML' 
is too long or invalid  D:\FooBarBaz\5000\5000 - xyz - xyxy - example - 
IRE\B2B.Common\Src\FooBarBaz.Core.Providers
.ScheduledTaskProviders\foobarbaz Search Alerting\CSC   
foobarbaz Search Alerting
```

The problem is, I can build it in VS2010 without any problem.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kchwc1f1.aspx) this error shows, when the filename with path is longer then 260 character. Actually it's 156.

So two questions are:

Why does this work in VS2010 and not 2012?

How can I solve this in VS2012?

Comment: Have you tried to simply shorten the length of the directory?

Comment: I can't do it, because it's not allowed... It's in source control, and there are some rules.

Comment: the error probably has shortened the path for your error, `..` isn't a valid folder name, so yes it probably is >260 characters. Where are you getting this error?

Comment: I've checked the phisycal file path in total commander and it was 156 character. I'm getting the error while I'm building the solution

Comment: can you attach the file path you are using to your question? feel free to obfuscate it as much as you want, replacing characters with different characters but not changing the format (i.e change letters for other letters but not slashes, dots, hyphens etc)

Comment: @Sayse: `..` is a valid folder name in a relative path. It means 'up one level from the current folder'. So if you're in 'C:\Projects\FolderA', using '..\' refers to 'C:\Projects', and '..\..\' refers to 'C:\'.

Comment: here is it: D:\Foobarb\5000\5000 - XYZ - XYXY - XYXYXYZ - IRE\B2B.Common\Documentation\Foobarb.Portfolio.Core.Providers.ScheduledTaskProviders.FooBarbSearchAlerting.xml

Comment: @speti43 - Copy the folder. Shorten the path, verify it works, suggest and report the solution. **You can't be the only one with the problem in your office.**

Comment: @KenWhite - I know I meant that vs may have shortened it to fit it into the error (and that OP was counting the characters of this)

Comment: I'm using only 2012, it works in 2010

Comment: I can use 2010 too, I've tried to upgrade, but I don't understand why not works in 2012 while it do in 2010

Comment: @speti43 - Have you tried to remove the file from the solution and add it back? Have you tried to modify the solution file by hand? **My suggestions are all simply tests to figure out solutions to the problem.**  I am going to guess its a problem with the migration process from 2010 to 2012, easy enough problem to solve, but different solutions must be tried.

Comment: What properties do you have for your build, is it copying it to the obj folder?

Comment: This file is in documentation outside the project folder, and I can't find it in the solution explorer. I'm searching the connection to the project. If I find somethimg I will post. Thanks for the help.

Comment: And you're certain that the relative path to the file from your VS 2012 solution is the same as the relative path to the file from your VS 2010 solution? Or are you opening the VS 2010 solution in VS 2012?

Comment: The spaces in that path are very suspicious to me. When you use it with VS 2010, you also have spaces in the full path? That can be important!

Comment: Yes I have spaces too in project's path, but I can't find the reference of that xml in the project, which is phisically outside of project folder. The error is shown only in VS2012 error list, but I can't navigate to the file and I can't find it in solution explorer. It's obscure, and I've given up searching the cause. It will be solved by refactoring or redesigning and rewriting... If I unload this project the solution builds succesfully in 2012. I build the rest in 2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue. File names can't be infinitely long. You need to redesign your naming conventions. Frankly, name, FooBarBaz.Portfolio.Core.Providers.ScheduledTaskProviders
.foobarbazSearchAlerting.XML is sadomasochism of computing.

To avoid this, I map my source control branches to simple c:\DEV\Branch_Name.

You definitely need to discuss this issue with your team and look to redesign your naming and foldering patterns. I would say, file should have no more than 3 part-names. `Company.Product.Business`

Please look at this blog. http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2156195-fix-260-character-file-name-length-limitation

This may help you

Comment: This project was not created and designed by me, so I understand your suggestion. But if it's invalid, how could it work in VS2010?

Comment: I added info in the answer. I had this issue before in VS2010. "project was not created and designed by me" - you in charge now :o)

Comment: Windows kernel/NTFS supports paths of approximately 32,000 characters and 255 per component of the path. In a modern operating system and file system, it makes no sense that you are restricted to a sub-260 character path limitation. The file system equivalent of "we'll only ever need 4kB of memory". In this day and age, we should not be restricted to C:\DEV\ for base folder and retroactively applying restricted naming conventions to the issues created by this limitation.

Comment: @Shiv Ok. So what is your point here? Visual Studio still having issues with long paths, regardless. Besides that, if you call your project `FooBarBaz.Core.Providers.ScheduledTaskProviders`, you better think of redesigning it. It really should be `Company.Product.Module` and as short as possible

Comment: Just that it's a regression that VS2012 has a lower limit than VS2010 and a counter-intuitive direction for the platform to be moving. Comment was pointing out that the process to find out about this limitation is backwards (you often are pretty deep in product development generally speaking to get paths this long) and there should be pressure on MS to make progress in this area. Also I do not agree that the naming conventions of the assembly is any business of external parties as there are no enforced standards in this area. The IDE should enforce constraints if that were the case.

Comment: @Shiv I had exactly same issue with VS2010 and ended up teaching the entire company how to download code into short paths.